# how to add value to slice in pie chart in ipad using coreplot , xcode

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-plot

I have  to display values in slices of pie chart which i created using  core plot in ipad .
can you Help me to sort out this ??

Regards,
Amit

Comment: Please post what you have done by now, and a specific question.

Comment: I have created a pie chart in ipad  which have four different slices .I want to add string value to each slice . How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the method I use to get text/data associated with the pie slices:

```
- (CPLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    static CPMutableTextStyle *whiteText = nil;
NSString *string = @"some text you want to insert or data from an array";

    if ( !whiteText ) {
        whiteText = [[CPMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
        whiteText.color = [CPColor whiteColor];
    }

    CPTextLayer *newLayer = nil;

    newLayer = [[[CPTextLayer alloc] initWithText:string style:whiteText] autorelease];

    return newLayer;
}
```

This is a standard method in core plot, so you shouldn't have to do anything more to make it work.  Just specify what you want in the text and it does the rest.  Hopefully that does the trick for you